# Find distinct values group by another field mongodb

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, distinct-values

I have collection with documents like this :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c0685fd6afbd73b80f45338"),
    "page_id" : "1234",
    "category_list" : [  
        "football", 
        "sport"
    ],
    "time_broadcast" : "09:13"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c0685fd6afbd7355f45338"),
    "page_id" : "1234",
    "category_list" : [ 
        "sport",
        "handball"
    ],
    "time_broadcast" : "09:13"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c0694ec6afbd74af41ea4af"),
    "page_id" : "123456",
    "category_list" : [ 
        "news", 
        "updates"
     ],
     "time_broadcast" : "09:13"
}
```

....

```
now = datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime("%H:%M")
```

What i want is : when "time_broadcast" is equal to "now",i get list of distinct "category_list" of each "page_id".

Here is how the output should look like :

```
{
   { 
     "page_id" : "1234",
     "category_list" : ["football", "sport", "handball"] 
   },

   { 
     "page_id" : "123456",
     "category_list" : ["news", "updates"] 
   }
}
```

I have tried like this :

```
category_list = db.users.find({'time_broadcast': now}).distinct("category_list")
```

but this gives me as output list of distinct values but

of all "page_id" :

```
 ["football", "sport", "handball","news", "updates"]
```

not category_list by page_id .

Any help please ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to write an aggregate pipeline

- `$match` - filter the documents by criteria
- `$group` - group the documents by key field
- `$addToSet` - aggregate the unique elements
- `$project` - project in the required format
- `$reduce` - reduce the array of array to array by `$concatArrays`

aggregate query

```
db.tt.aggregate([
    {$match : {"time_broadcast" : "09:13"}}, 
    {$group : {"_id" : "$page_id", "category_list" : {$addToSet : "$category_list"}}}, 
    {$project : {"_id" : 0, "page_id" : "$_id", "category_list" : {$reduce : {input : "$category_list", initialValue : [], in: { $concatArrays : ["$$value", "$$this"] }}}}}
]).pretty()
```

result

```
{ "page_id" : "123456", "category_list" : [ "news", "updates" ] }
{
        "page_id" : "1234",
        "category_list" : [
                "sport",
                "handball",
                "football",
                "sport"
        ]
}
```

you can add `$sort` by `page_id` pipeline if required