# MongoDB aggregate get distinct values of field and output list of another field

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a MongoDB collection with documents like:

```
{'city': 'NYC', 'value': 'blue'},
{'city': 'NYC', 'value': 'red'},
{'city': 'Boston', 'value': 'blue'},
{'city': 'Boston', 'value': 'green'}
```

I want to aggregate distinct values of city with a list of distinct values of value, like:

```
{'city': 'NYC', 'values': ['blue', 'red']},
{'city': 'Boston', 'values': ['blue', 'green']}
```

How can I do this in a PyMongo pipeline?

Something with a shell like:

```
cursor = db.aggregate([
        {'$group': {
            '_id': {
                'value': '$value',
                'city': '$city'
            }
        }},
])
```

Comment: look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53836634/8987128), you just need a $group stage like this answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `_id` field of the group, you should specify only the keys you want to be grouped by (`city` in your case).

Followed by that key, the rest of the keys are additional keys you want from the query result. `$addToSet` will append each finding of the grouped field to an array without duplicates.

Below is the Aggregation code you are looking for:

```
cursor = db.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$city",
      "value": {
        "$addToSet": "$value"
      }
    }
  },
])
```

In the about code, `_id` consists of grouped city names.